# how do I access my own variables in the user class fos_userBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am new to symfony, I am trying to learn about accessing the user variables.

This is how I can retrieve the username:

```
$this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getUsername();
```

But how can I retrieve a variable that I created myself, in my case the $company(int)?
I have tried to do

```
    $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getCompany();
```

Then it returns me an object that seems to be of infinite size, chrome just never stops loading that page if I do a var_dump on it!

Comment: @mask8 It's a private or protected property, so he has to call the getter...

Comment: Use `\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump(...)` instead of `var_dump`.

Comment: @MattiasSvensson It's generally a great idea to install Xdebug (http://xdebug.org/). It'll spit out more readable and compact var_dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming company is another entity that you've linked to the user via a foreign key?

If so, doing a var_dump will pretty much dump a whole lot of information you dont need.
Either output a specific variable of the company so
$this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getCompany()->getName();
or attempt to cast it to a string like
$this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getCompany()->__toString();

You'd have to implement the toString method anyway but it's always good to do as it means in twig templates you can get something like this {{ app.user.company }} instead of {{ app.user.company.name}}